# INSERT INTO MSSQL (...) SELECT ... FROM Csv

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, insert

I have a huge problem right now and am unsure how to solve it. I have a process or rather a bunch of similar processes which import csv-files into our MSSQL-Database. We used SSIS for this earlier, but it's just not practical, because you have to build 1 SSIS-Pakage per process and we have about 20 of those.

That is why I'm working on a way to do the same thing with one application in C# and Sql, but I'm already failing with the csv-import. I need to find a way to do an insert into statement where I can declare both the select-columns for the Sql-Table as well as the selection for the csv.

I really have no clue how to do this or if it is even possible. That's why I'm hoping you guys know of a way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but did you even bother to read my post? This doesn't help at all, because it creates a new table with the same metadata as the csv...

Comment: have a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439843/Handling-BULK-Data-insert-from-CSV-to-SQL-Server

Comment: Are you serious? Read my post for gods sake or please dont answer at all!

Comment: I use 2 libraries to do what you ask but It is slow: LinqToCSV and CsvHelper Tou can find it on Nuget. And if you don't have example I can give you mines. Hope it will help you

Comment: It's slow huh? Well .. I need something fast, as it isn't unusual that these csvs contain 100.000+ rows. Well thanks anyways. I'll have a look at this stuff. (Finally somehow that actually read my post)

Comment: Found something that looks about right ..h ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978275/how-to-use-sqlbulkcopycolumnmappingcollection

Comment: @user854699: yes, I was serious! I gave you a link as a comment and not as an answer. If you would have followed it you would have found an example for SqlBulkCopy usage and could have gone from there

Comment: An example that is absolutely useless and relates in no way to my problem, congrats ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlBulkCopy or rather SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping is the right way to do it. It's even implemented for DB2.